# Acces Windows COM port from docker(linux container)

Tags: windows, docker, docker-container, com-port

I need to have acces to windows com port(COM3) form docker linux contianer:
I tried like this:

```
docker run -d --name test_com_port -p 8090:80 --device=/dev/ttyACM14 --restart always test_com_port

docker run -d --name test_com_port -p 8090:80 –-device=COM3:/dev/ttyS2
 --restart always test_com_port

docker run -d --name test_com_port -p 8090:80 –-device=//./COM3:/dev/ttyS2
 --restart always test_com_port
```

but don't have any results. Also I visited [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/hardware-devices-in-containers?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5002324) but it is only for windows containers. Maybe some one have any solutions how to solve it?

Comment: have you found a solution? i think there is some evolution, but I'm still working on it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb

Answer (score 2):

hey there I was successfully able to map a windows serial device to a docker container, it was a long and tedious task but in the end I was successful. Any who has access to windows 10 with support for WSL 2 can follow these steps:

1.) Install WSL 2 with Ubuntu distro as it's easier to work with.

2.) On the windows host machine install this software called usbipd through command `winget install usbipd` for more information use this [link](https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win)

3.)Now we have to configure a few things in the Ubuntu distro so that the interfacing happens for that you will have to follow this [link](https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win/wiki/WSL-support)

4.)Once that is done you can now mount the device, before we start the mounting process make sure to plug-in the device to the windows host

5.)Before mounting you can check the list of available devices with `usbipd wsl list`. You will be able to see all the serial devices connected and now you can
interface or mount or attach using the command `usbipd wsl attach --busid=<BUSID>`

6.)Once the device is attached you can open the wsl Ububtu use the command `lsusb` to check all available serial devices which communicate over USB.

7.)Now the final step is to mount the device to docker container with command `--device /dev/<available port>`; ex `doecker run -d --device=/dev/<available ports from liunx ubuntu distro> <container>`

Comment: could you precise the value of  `<available ports from linux ubuntu>`? In my wsl2 Ubuntu `lsusb` gives `Bus 001 Device 003` so I enter `--device dev/bus/usb/001/003` for my docker container?

Comment: @AntoineNguyen, in linux pc the usb to ttl converter will be displayed as **ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1** etc. you can view this by first doing `cd  /dev` then `ls` to view, when device is not connected the options  ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 will not appear on screen there will be plenty of other things like **ttyS1, ttyS2 etc**, when you connect the device  **ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1** etc , will appear. that time use the command `--device /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0` etc

Comment: @Harshith Yadav I can use usbipd and successfully attached. However my Linux only create /dev/ttyS0 ~ ttyS3. There is no ttyUSB11 or ttyS11 (My serial port in Win 11 is COM11). Any idea how to fix this?