# Unable to run the ESP-IDF docker container in Windows

Tags: docker, esp32, docker-desktop, esp-idf, espressif-idf

I am unable to successfully start the ESP-IDF container in Windows. I have managed to forward my serial port through to WSL2 so I can see it in Ubuntu, but the container won't fire up. The Error message is very cryptic and I'm at a loss for what to try next.

I'm following [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8S1f1YnKr0&t=747s) walk-through on how to set up and run the ESP-IDF docker. The guy running this is working on a linux machine and I have set up the container on Docker Desktop on windows.

So far I have successfully:

- Set up the docker extension on VS code
- [Attached my USB port through to WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467148/acces-windows-com-port-from-dockerlinux-container) (which is required to start up the container)
- started the docker engine to the point where it has pulled the docker image and attempted to start up the container.

I have the following code in my .devcontainer folder:
Dockerfile:

```
ARG USER=me
ARG UID=1000

FROM espressif/idf:v4.4.1

ARG UID
ARG USER

# Create Non-Root User
RUN ["dash", "-c", "\
    addgroup \
     --gid ${UID} \
     \"${USER}\" \
 && adduser \
     --disabled-password \
     --gecos \"\" \
     --ingroup \"${USER}\" \
     --uid ${UID} \
     \"${USER}\" \
 && usermod \
     --append \
     --groups \"dialout,plugdev\" \
     \"${USER}\" \
    "]

RUN echo "source /opt/esp/idf/export.sh" >> /root/.bashrc
```

devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "ESP-IDF",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "settings": {
        "idf.showOnboardingOnInit": false,
        "idf.espIdsPath": "opt/esp/idf",
        "idf.pythonBinPat": "/opt/esp/python_env/idf4.4_py3.6_env/bin/python",
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "extensions": [
        "twxs.cmake",
        "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    ], 
    "userEnvProbe": "loginInteractiveShell",

    "runArgs": [
        "-t",
        "-i",
        "--device=/dev/ttyUSB0",
        "ubuntu", 
        "bash"
    ],

    "remoteUser": "me"
}
```

But the container throws a very cryptic error:

```
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.565Z] Start: Resolving Remote
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.567Z] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.634Z] Stop (67 ms): Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.636Z] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.811Z] Stop (175 ms): Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.812Z] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container 91389f8f4e97
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.996Z] Stop (184 ms): Run: docker inspect --type container 91389f8f4e97
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.996Z] Start: Starting container
[2023-09-11T09:40:28.996Z] Start: Run: docker start 91389f8f4e97e9252d8b2948a919d8b1239dad8a8aeb862d4e4eb596701bc8f0
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.414Z] Stop (418 ms): Run: docker start 91389f8f4e97e9252d8b2948a919d8b1239dad8a8aeb862d4e4eb596701bc8f0
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.416Z] Error: Command failed: docker start 91389f8f4e97e9252d8b2948a919d8b1239dad8a8aeb862d4e4eb596701bc8f0
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.417Z]     at gAA (c:\Users\My.Name \.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:462:1066)
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.417Z]     at FK (c:\Users\My.Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:462:1002)
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.417Z]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.417Z]     at async FAA (c:\Users\My.Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:479:3660)
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.417Z]     at async GC (c:\Users\My.Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:479:4775)
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.417Z]     at async VeA (c:\Users\My.Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:611:12240)
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.417Z]     at async WeA (c:\Users\My.Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:611:11981)
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.426Z] Stop (1490 ms): Run: C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\My.Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-a1eee3f5-accf-40da-93b2-f81ba8ab69041694425224200 --workspace-folder c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\mnt\wslg\runtime-dir\wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-83642a2a-fe1e-4219-98a2-504f80e19d5a.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true --terminal-columns 215 --terminal-rows 8
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.426Z] Exit code 1
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.429Z] Command failed: C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\My.Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-a1eee3f5-accf-40da-93b2-f81ba8ab69041694425224200 --workspace-folder c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE --id-label devcontainer.config_file=c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Software\sandbox\Docker\ESP-IDE\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\mnt\wslg\runtime-dir\wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-83642a2a-fe1e-4219-98a2-504f80e19d5a.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true --terminal-columns 215 --terminal-rows 8
[2023-09-11T09:40:29.429Z] Exit code 1
```

I'm new to docker so any words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Updated Docker and re-installed the container and everything works. Note that the devcontainer.jason file should read:

```
{
    "name": "ESP-IDF",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "customizations/vscode/settings": {
        "idf.showOnboardingOnInit": false,
        "idf.espIdsPath": "opt/esp/idf",
        "idf.pythonBinPat": "/opt/esp/python_env/idf4.4_py3.6_env/bin/python",
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "customizations/vscode/extensions": [
        "twxs.cmake",
        "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    ], 
    "userEnvProbe": "loginInteractiveShell",

    "runArgs": [
        "--device=/dev/ttyUSB0"
    ],

    "remoteUser": "me"
}
```

The random run arguments and old vs code settings locations are just here as a red herring